# SSL certificate from RapidSSL not working as expected on some Android phones

Tags: ssl

I bought an SSL certificate from RapidSSL for [my website](https://lazyair.co).

It works on an iPhone and desktop browsers but it’s working on some Android phones; see picture below. The error is “NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.”

Is there any alternative SSL provider can let all devices won’t show “warning” problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress Google Chrome's "Your Connection is Not Private" for specific Address?](http://superuser.com/questions/960850/suppress-google-chromes-your-connection-is-not-private-for-specific-address)

Comment: Related: [How to always allow insecure connection for a certain url in chrome?](http://superuser.com/q/1004794/87805)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your certificate. It is possible that some browsers are able to resolve the intermediate chain and thus they don't complain about your root + intermediate + your site certificate combination.

Indeed, on a broser in Android, it shows up the `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, which seems to mean the following:

> This error is caused by a missing intermediate CA.
>
> Please ensure you have downloaded and installed the required
>   intermediate CA for your certificate.

Simply verify you put the intermediate CA in the correct order, or if you added them all. If unsure, contact your CA provider. As I said, it's not a problem of the certificate which seems good (and doesn't support weak ciphers).

Comment: I think in english, it just means 'SSL certificate is not trusted '