# Getting Certificate error on IE and Chrome but opens in FireFox

Tags: ssl-certificate, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to open https://github.com on IE 11 and Chrome but it gives a SSL certificate error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` on chrome with no option to proceed ahead.

It's happening with almost every site but luckily I am getting the option to proceed. Then I installed Firefox (portable version) and checked that it works without any problem!

Digging further I found that Firefox is using system proxy settings and I do not see any settings in IE and  Chrome. What could go wrong . How to fix this ?

I have tried a lot changing the Advanced Security setting in Internet Explorer but no help.

Comment: Check the date and time of your computer and make sure it's within 5 minutes of a known correct source for your time zone...

Comment: when you migrate questions from one forum to another make sure the solutions proposed are not lost. Eventually I lost some comments in the migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress Google Chrome's "Your Connection is Not Private" for specific Address?](http://superuser.com/questions/960850/suppress-google-chromes-your-connection-is-not-private-for-specific-address)

Comment: This is not a possible duplicate . See the solution provided below . Guys -stop making yourself busy in making questions duplicate and migrating questions from one forum to another. This is why I see a lot people moving on expert-exchange .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually , **this got solved when I posted the same question  on expert-exchage.com**.

The problem was that either the browser (Chrome and IE both) were not downloading the correct certificate or it was not in the Trusted Root CA directory.  I downloaded the CORRECT certificate from

https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt

and installed it in Trusted root CA directory and it worked like a charm.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28854099/Getting-Certificate-error-on-IE-and-Chrome-but-opens-in-FireFox.html

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with expired root CA's that was reported with Chrome some time back. You can find a thread here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/SE3sKXg0iFQ

It seems that deleting and replacing some DigiCert certificates resolved the issue for quite a lot of people. The thread above includes instructions to do that.

Comment: Thnx but I already have tried this. This is actually not applicable for me as the certificate I am receiving from github is already valid till 2016. Also if certificate expiry was the reason , it should not have worked in firefox as well !

Comment: Even if the site certificate is valid - there could be an issue with the root certificate that verifies the site certificate. Real or imagined - I see those problems quite often.

Are you able to view the certificate chain from Chrome? If so - make sure that Chrome doesn't flag up any (possibly made-up) errors.

Also, IIRC, Firefox uses a different cerfificate store than Chrome and IE so it could be that Firefox's root ca for whoever signs github is different. Could be worth looking at.