# Chrome HSTS Error: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, security, certificate

I am using a self-signed certificate on my openmediavault setup. On Firefox, there is an option to add an exception to that, but on Chrome it complains with the error code: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

It also does not allow me to continue the unsecure website and displays the following error:

> xxx.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When
>   Chrome tried to connect to xxx.com this time, xxx.com returned unusual
>   and incorrect credentials. Either an attacker is trying to pretend to
>   be twitter.com, or a Wi-Fi login screen has interrupted the
>   connection. Your information is still secure because Chrome stopped
>   the connection before any data was exchanged. 
>        Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

I tried to use Incognito window, but it is the same error.

I also imported the self-signed certificate by exporting and then double-clicking on it.

Using Windows 10

PS: I also used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1000003/getting-certificate-error-on-ie-and-chrome-but-opens-in-firefox) but did not solve my issue.

Comment: This is a certificate problem.  You can get around it by typing "danger" within chrome at the certificate error page.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/1038690/problems-with-chrome-browser?noredirect=1#comment1451371_1038690)