# Your connection is not private google chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am using Windows 7. In chrome, a lot of websites are not opening. An error shows when I start browsing a website, [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBwBi.png).

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   idioms.thefreedictionary.com (for example, passwords, messages, or
>   credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

The same website is opening in Mozilla firefox.

Here is the snapshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysoIc.png) , [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zicj.png) , [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFj5y.png) , [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im7g4.png)

Comment: Possible dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/1000003/getting-certificate-error-on-ie-and-chrome-but-opens-in-firefox

Comment: @DavidPostill I have already followed the steps given on the page but it did not help me https://superuser.com/a/1002748/1162205

Comment: The problem is with the website itself.  The website is not properly configured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Certificate error on IE and Chrome but opens in FireFox](https://superuser.com/questions/1000003/getting-certificate-error-on-ie-and-chrome-but-opens-in-firefox)

Comment: @Ramhound But the website is working on my laptop. Same browser (chrome) and same internet connection. [I checked this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1000003/getting-certificate-error-on-ie-and-chrome-but-opens-in-firefox) but it did not help. So posted a question.

Comment: Here is the snapshot [1](https://i.imgur.com/uat7ije.png) , [2](https://i.imgur.com/d679cEj.png) , [3](https://i.imgur.com/QBGcjC6.png) , [4](https://i.imgur.com/erKpLTx.png)

Comment: @linoff123 - I got the same error on multiple devices.  Which is an indication the problem is the website configuration not a user configuration error.  Your first screenshot, clearly indicates, the certificate is **invalid**  Your 4th screenshot indicates the reason the certificate for the domain is invalid.

Comment: @Ramhound same error in thesaurus.com , dictionary.com , collinsdictionary.com , ldoceonline.com and lot of other websites.

Comment: @linoff123 - I am not going to check each of those websites, but I guarantee you, the certificate errors are due to  legitimate errors with the certificate itself

Comment: @Ramhound How do I check and add a certificate? I installed the certificate from https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt but it did not help me.

Comment: You screenshot indicates you already know how to check if a certificate is valid or invalid.

Comment: @Ramhound https://i.imgur.com/d679cEj.png it's showing that certificate is ok..

Comment: @linoff123 - https://i.imgur.com/uat7ije.png and https://i.imgur.com/erKpLTx.pngis showing it's invalid.  You have a single node selected, all nodes must contain no errors, in order for Firefox to consider the connection secure.  I went to this website in Edge (EdgeHTML), Chrome, and Firefox on multiple PCs. They all show the the first domain as being an insecure connection (i.e. certificate invalid error)

Answer (score 5):

As I can see, the scale of this issue is occurring on the entire of your Windows 7 computer (happening on all web browsers), but it doesn't occur on your laptop (on the same network).

For this reason, I can jump into a conclusion, that is something goes wrong on your Windows 7 computer.

There are a few things you need to check, according to [this guide](https://bytebitebit.com/687/your-connection-is-not-private/), such as:

- Make sure the date and time of your Windows 7 PC are correct.
- Is there any antivirus software on your computer. Let's temporarily turn it off and check again those web browsers. Sometimes, the HTTPS filter/scanner feature blocks HTTPS connections and cause this issue.
- Flush the DNS cache in Windows with the ipconfig /flushdns command. There are maybe a few outdated DNS entries on your computer.

Get back to me the result so I can help further.